# How to play infinitely a ".wav" file using python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, wave

I'm trying to play the ".wav" file infinitely to use in my experiment.

I'm using the script of the pyaudio website (http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/), however it plays for only 5 seconds.

I tried to use the code below, but it plays for some seconds.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

while True:
    CHUNK = 20*100

    wf = 
    wave.open('Metano_Ref_Lockin=SR830_mod=0.460V_freq=3936_PP=20_NP=100.wav', 'rb')
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

   p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

   stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=wf.getnchannels(),
            rate=wf.getframerate(),
            output_device_index=4,
            output=True)


   while data != '':
      stream.write(data)
      data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

   stream.stop_stream()
   stream.close()
   p.terminate()
```

On the other hand, this code works, nevertheless, the signal is not uniform (some noises appear).

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 20*100

wf = wave.open('Metano_Ref_Lockin=SR830_mod=0.460V_freq=3936_PP=20_NP=100.wav', 'rb')
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=wf.getnchannels(),
            rate=wf.getframerate(),
            output_device_index=4,
            output=True)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

I expect a uniform signal to be reproduced infinitely.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data comparison should be

```
while data != b'':
    ...
```

or the simpler variant (empty strings cast to `False`):

```
while data:
    ...
```

Also, you really should reuse `wf`, `stream`, and `p` inbetween loops:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 2 ** 11

wf = wave.open('Metano_Ref_Lockin=SR830_mod=0.460V_freq=3936_PP=20_NP=100.wav', 'rb')

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
        channels=wf.getnchannels(),
        rate=wf.getframerate(),
        output=True)


while True:
    wf.rewind()

    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
    while data:
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

wf.close()
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: Thank you. The first and second option did not work. But I succeeded by using the third.